# Rails public/assets folder keeps growing, creating heroku trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a relatively simple Rails application which has a few coffeescript files that I need to change occasionally.

The public assets folder keeps growing with new files every time I am forced to recompile in order to push to heroku. When this happens I have new asset file that I have to add to git in order for them to be pushed to Heroku for my JS and CSS to appear (if I do not add these new files and push I am left with no CSS or JS).

Obviously I have got the wrong end of the stick here somehow, and am creating extra unnecessary files.

Can anyone shed light on this? I am including a screenshot of my public/assets directory so you get the picture:

[image]

Comment: It's also worth noting that you don't need to precompile assets before pushing to Heroku, they are compiled at deployment time however it does add to the deployment time if you have many assets.

Comment: They weren't compiling though, that was the problem. I was making changes to my coffeescript and nothing would happen after I committed and pushed (I was left with the previous version). I read through the heroku assets guides and the only thing that worked was precompiling, so I stuck with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you run `rake assets:precompile`, clean up your old assets:

with either `rake assets:clean`

which only removes old assets (keeps the most recent 3 copies) from public/assets. Useful when doing rolling deploys that may still be serving old assets while the new ones are being compiled.

or `rake assets:clobber`

which empties out public/assets and clears the Sprockets file system cache.

Source: https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/blob/master/README.md

Note that `rake assets:clobber` is for Rails 4 only.